# Google Sitemap for multiple domains of same site

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap, multiple-domains

I have a website and its domain has been used for several years. Now I want to use an additional new name for the site, so I got a new domain. There are four valid addresses now: `http://old.com`, `http://www.old.com`, `http://new.com`, `http://www.new.com`, and they all show the same site; they are synonyms (no re-direction).

I am using Google Webmaster Service. So far my sitemap contained lines for `http://www.old.com` (and I always wondered whether I should have `http://old.com` in there, too, thus listing each page twice). <- This would be my first question: should I or not? Would it be good or bad or wouldn't it matter at all?

Now the same site can also be called via `http://new.com` and `http://www.new.com`. What to do now? Add this as a *new* website in Google Webmaster Service? This seems ridiculous, as it is the *same* site (with another name). And I would even fear that Google might feel betrayed and punish my site with a low rank for the duplicate post.

However, the new addresses *do* exist. So where to tell Google that this is the case? How to make Google know that `http://old.com` = `http://www.old.com` = `http://new.com` = `http://www.new.com`?

And: How to write the sitemap that I submit to Google? Shall it contain one domain only or both? The Website is registered with Google as `www.old.com`. Would I even be allowed to have `www.new.com` in the same sitemap? Would it do good or bad?

I already read on https://support.google.com/webmasters, but didn't find answers to my (rather basic?) questions. I don't use Google Analytics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are four valid addresses...and they all show the same site; they are synonyms (no re-direction).

Prior to considering your sitemap, which is not *essential* for Google to index your site, you should deal with all the [duplicate content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en) issues you have going on here. As covered in [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en) Google Webmaster Tools help doc:

> *Duplicate content generally refers to substantive blocks of content within or across domains that either completely match other content or are appreciably similar.*

You should therefore pick one domain, and one URL version of that domain (e.g., `www.new.com` if preferred), and `301` redirect all the others to this so that Google doesn't crawl and find the same content on each of these URLs.

That also includes doing a `301` redirect from one URL version of `new.com` to the other (e.g., `http://new.com` -> `http://www.new.com`). You should also indicate to Google that this is the [preferred](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231) version of your site using [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en).

Last but not least, it's a good idea to let Google know that your site moved to the new address using the [change of address tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en).

With that completed, you can then list all the URLs that correspond to one version (e.g., `http://www.new.com`) in your sitemap without concern for duplicate content penalties from all the others.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for this comprehensive answer. And thank you very much for poining me to the change of address tool I didn't know of.

Comment: No problem. Though focused on the protocol, my answer [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56249/impact-of-migrating-whole-site-from-http-to-https) in regards to moving a site contains even more steps and reference links. Good luck!